# writing to 2D vector, is crashing my program

Tags: c++

I'm new to vectors programming, so my code is buggy:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > v, w;

    if (in) {
        std::string line;

        while (std::getline(in, line)) {
            v.push_back(std::vector<int>());

            for(int x=0; x<line.size(); x++){
                v.back().push_back((int)line[x] - (int)'0');
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++)
            std::cout << v[i][j] << ' ';

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    int size = v.size(); //because its a square matrix
    w = v; //w is our temp vector for storing new values;
    int alive =0;
    int z=0;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<size; j++)
        {
            alive = 0;
            for(int c = -1;c<2; c++)
            {
                for(int d = -1; d<2 ; d++)
                {
                    if(!(c==0 && d == 0))
                    {
                        z = v[i+c][j+d];
                        if(z)
                            ++alive;
                    }
                }

                if(alive<2) w[i].push_back(0);
                else if(alive == 3) w[i].push_back(1);
                else w[i].push_back(0);
            }
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think I am assigning values into my second variable wrong. My program reads from an input file along the lines:

```
1010101
0101010
1010101
```

and is to write to the second vector `w` after analyzing its neighbors (game of life problem), I think I should use `w.push_back()` but I'm not sure on the syntax for a 2D vector. Is there a better way to push the variable?

Comment: `z = v[i+c][j+d];` -- Change that to `z = v.at(i+c).at(j+d);` -- Then diagnose the `std::out_of_range` exception that is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that I notice right away.  The main one that is causing your crash is you are accessing outside of the bounds for the `v` array.  This happens when `i` is 0 and `c` is -1, and can also happen when `i` is `size-1` and `c` is +1 (the same thing happens with `j` and `d`).

The other issue is with how you save the `alive` value into `w`.  Since you start with `w = v`, you have all the elements you need.  Just replace them with, for example, `w[i][j] = 0`.  (You'll also want to move that conditional block outside of the `c` loop.)